# Tar path issue in PHP

Tags: php, command, exec, tar

I am trying to create a TAR through `exec` in PHP, which will contain lots of folders. Each of the included folders represent a server path. Unfortunately my script to create this TAR is not working and I don't know what am I doing wrong. Linux is not my strongest point, so if anyone has an idea about what might be going wrong I would appreciate some insight.

**CODE**

```
 exec("tar czf ".DIR_PATH."/public/zip_folder/facebook_albums_1.tar.gz / ".DIR_PATH."public/zip_folder/facebook_albums_1");
```

**CODE RESULT**

```
var\chroot\home\content\78\10368378\html\domain\Facebook\public\zip_folder\facebook_albums_1
```

**I WANT**

```
zip_folder\facebook_albums_1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing

`chdir(DIR_PATH . '/public/');`

before `exec`, and then just change `exec` to

```
exec("tar czf zip_folder/facebook_albums_1.tar.gz zip_folder/facebook_albums_1");
```

Comment: $path ? to define this can you please elaborate @Marko D